# What does the phrase "with suspect allegiances required to combat a powerful enemy" mean exactly here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"It [*The Tragedy of Othello*] would rewrite *Henry V* by offering another version of the story of an ambivalent heroic warrior with suspect allegiances required to combat a powerful enemy, who is pushed to his physical and emotional limits and marries outside his community." (Jerry Brotton, *This Orient Isle- Elizabethan England and the Islamic World*)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That text could do with some commas to make it a little easier to parse, IMO.  Eg

> "It would rewrite Henry V by offering another version of the story, of
> an ambivalent heroic warrior with suspect allegiances, required to
> combat a powerful enemy, who is pushed to his physical and emotional
> limits, and marries outside his community."

So, the segment you asked about is now part of two different phrases:

*It would rewrite Henry V by offering another version of the story*,

*of an ambivalent heroic warrior with suspect allegiances*
(the warrior's *allegiances* are suspect, ie under suspicion)

and that warrior experiences the following things:

1. he is required to combat a powerful enemy
2. he is pushed to his physical and emotional limits
3. he marries outside his community